# Why do sessions need to be stored on a sites server?

Tags: php, session, cookies, browser, server-side

I was just wondering why sessions need to be stored on a sites server...I know its because its inaccessible so user sessions cannot be changed, but then why do you need cookies? Why can you not just have one type of data containers which are always stored in a server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not have one flavour of ice cream and one model of car

Comment: How would you connect the session to the users browser?

Answer (score 2):

HTTP is stateless by design, you need cookies to have sessions in the first place. Sure, you could add a phpsessionid to every URL, but then you just made your URL's a mess and put state where it doesn't belong.

Cookies exist to add small amounts of state, if you are just using PHP sessions then all they need is to store a phpsessionid and you are done. However, maybe you have preferences that a user could set that don't necessitate the usage of a full-blown session, cookies provide a great method of saving this data without costing disk space on your server.

Cookies and sessions (and now local storage) for that matter are not mutually exclusive, use the right tool for the right job.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple, when you close your browser, session storage is removed, in cookies you can for example store usernames, so they are allready filled in when the user re-visits your site